# How can a standard domain user find the path to their Active Directory DC?

Tags: active-directory

I have a program that does some great stuff but needs an LDAP path to be provided to identify the set of users that it's interested in. How can I describe to a relatively non-tech user how to find this for their environment? They'll basically want the LDAP path to the DC or OU that contains all the users within the company, or at least for their office or some other big group, e.g. `LDAP://dc=MyFirm,dc=com` or `LDAP://ou=AllFolk,dc=MyFirm,dc=com`. I realise that in some companies this will be complicated and need different paths for different sets of users, but if we assume that there's a single OU or DC that will contain everyone how would a normal person go about finding the LDAP path to it?

A related question: how would a normal user find the name they should provide to use sysinternals AD Explorer, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a search option or start query to your program, where they can enter a domain\username to serch for, then retrieve from that the info you need.

Answer (score -1):

Use AD Explorer from Sysinternals, found [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963907.aspx).

Comment: How can they use it to find the path? As mentioned in the question and screenshot, you need to provide details to AD Explorer for it to work.